# org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent cannot be cast to my own object

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, classcastexception, roweditor

I want save the changes of a datatable in my DB but appear the exception: java.lang.String cannot be cast to jpa.TcamposEncuesta. I don't understand it. This is part of my ManagedBean and it extends the class TcamposEncuesta.

```
public void onEditRow(RowEditEvent event){
    try {    
        TcamposEncuesta tobj = (TcamposEncuesta)event.getObject();
        this.setIdcamposEncuesta(tobj.getIdcamposEncuesta());
        this.setNombre(((TcamposEncuesta) event.getObject()).getNombre());
        this.setAmplitud(((TcamposEncuesta) event.getObject()).getAmplitud());
        Properties pr = this.actualizarInsertar();
        String id = pr.getProperty("ID");
        addMessage("Ha modificado a: " + id);
    } catch(Exception e){
        addMessage(row+ "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

With any tests I caught errors in the both types of casting that I have.

This is my .xhtml, I put a datatable inside of datascroller and this works.

```
 <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
        <p:dataScroller id="idScroller" value="#{mbCamposEncuesta.listCamp}" var="campoEnc" chunkSize="2">
            <!-- <f:facet name="header">
                Scroll para cargar más elementos
            </f:facet> -->
            <f:facet name="loader">          
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Cargar más" icon="fa fa-angle-double-down" />
            </f:facet> 
            <p:dataTable id="idDataTable" editable="true" value="campoEnc" styleClass="dTable">
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{mbCamposEncuesta.onEditRow}" update=":form:msgs"/>
                    <!-- <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"   /> -->

                    <p:column>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output" ><h:outputText value="#{campoEnc.idcamposEncuesta}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input" ><p:inputText value="#{campoEnc.idcamposEncuesta}" disabled="true" /></f:facet> 
                    </p:cellEditor> 
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                    <p:cellEditor >
                        <f:facet name="output" ><h:outputText value="#{campoEnc.nombre}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input" ><p:inputText value="#{campoEnc.nombre}" /></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputLabel value="#{campoEnc.amplitud}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputNumber value="#{campoEnc.amplitud}" /></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output" ><h:outputText value="#{campoEnc.script}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input" ><p:inputText value="#{campoEnc.script}" disabled="true" /></f:facet> 
                    </p:cellEditor> 
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                    <p:cellEditor >
                        <f:facet name="output" ><h:outputText value="#{campoEnc.tipoCampo}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input" ><p:inputText value="#{campoEnc.tipoCampo}" /></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputLabel value="#{campoEnc.idlista}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputNumber value="#{campoEnc.idlista}" /></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width:32px">
                        <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
        </p:dataScroller>
    </h:form>
```

The Stack:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to jpa.TcamposEncuesta
at com.beans.jsfprograma.MbCamposEncuesta.onEditRow(MbCamposEncuesta.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processArgListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:79)
at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:63)
at org.primefaces.event.AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.java:38)
at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:804)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1086)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Stack: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to jpa.TcamposEncuesta
    at com.beans.jsfprograma.MbCamposEncuesta.onEditRow(MbCamposEncuesta.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processArgListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.event.AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.java:38)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:804)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1086)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is my object:

```
package jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Miguel Morales
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "TCAMPOS_ENCUESTA", catalog = "", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TcamposEncuesta.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TcamposEncuesta t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TcamposEncuesta.findByIdcamposEncuesta", query = "SELECT t FROM TcamposEncuesta t WHERE t.idcamposEncuesta = :idcamposEncuesta"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TcamposEncuesta.findByNombre", query = "SELECT t FROM TcamposEncuesta t WHERE t.nombre = :nombre"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TcamposEncuesta.findByTipoCampo", query = "SELECT t FROM TcamposEncuesta t WHERE t.tipoCampo = :tipoCampo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TcamposEncuesta.findByAmplitud", query = "SELECT t FROM TcamposEncuesta t WHERE t.amplitud = :amplitud"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TcamposEncuesta.findByIdlista", query = "SELECT t FROM TcamposEncuesta t WHERE t.idlista = :idlista"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "TcamposEncuesta.findByFechaCreacion", query = "SELECT t FROM TcamposEncuesta t WHERE t.fechaCreacion = :fechaCreacion")})
public class TcamposEncuesta extends Statement implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "IDCAMPOS_ENCUESTA", nullable = false)
    private Integer idcamposEncuesta = 0;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE", length = 10)
    private String nombre;
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "SCRIPT", length = 2147483647)
    private String script;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "TIPO_CAMPO", length = 1)
    private String tipoCampo;
    @Column(name = "AMPLITUD")
    private Integer amplitud;
    @Column(name = "IDLISTA")
    private Integer idlista;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "FECHA_CREACION", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaCreacion;


    public TcamposEncuesta() {
    }

    public TcamposEncuesta(Integer idcamposEncuesta) {
        this.idcamposEncuesta = idcamposEncuesta;
    }

    public TcamposEncuesta(Integer idcamposEncuesta, Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.idcamposEncuesta = idcamposEncuesta;
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }

    public Integer getIdcamposEncuesta() {
        return idcamposEncuesta;
    }

    public void setIdcamposEncuesta(Integer idcamposEncuesta) {
        this.idcamposEncuesta = idcamposEncuesta;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getScript() {
        return script;
    }

    public void setScript(String script) {
        this.script = script;
    }

    public String getTipoCampo() {
        return tipoCampo;
    }

    public void setTipoCampo(String tipoCampo) {
        this.tipoCampo = tipoCampo;
    }

    public Integer getAmplitud() {
        return amplitud;
    }

    public void setAmplitud(Integer amplitud) {
        this.amplitud = amplitud;
    }

    public Integer getIdlista() {
        return idlista;
    }

    public void setIdlista(Integer idlista) {
        this.idlista = idlista;
    }

    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return fechaCreacion;
    }

    public void setFechaCreacion(Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have an exception, it is standard practice to POST IT and ITS STACK TRACE. That then tells you where to concentrate your DEBUGGING, and what info to post in the "question"

Comment: So, what you recommend me to do? Sorry I don't understand what you tell me

Comment: I only caught this: java.lang.String cannot be cast to jpa.TcamposEncuesta.

Comment: Is it enough to help?

Comment: Enough to tell you that the exception happens at MbCamposEncuesta.java line 100. Only you know what line that is

Comment: Its just in the cast: TcamposEncuesta tobj = (TcamposEncuesta) obj;

Comment: so where does "event" come from and why is its object a String?!

Comment: I put the event inside of tags  <p:dataTable id="idDataTable" editable="true" value="campoEnc" styleClass="dTable">   <!-- Here: -->
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{mbCamposEncuesta.onEditRow}" update=":form:msgs"/>